# How to complete ML type-inference algorithm given a parse graph

Tags: algorithm, parsing, types, sml, ml

I want to try using a ML type-inference algorithm for a specific function declaration. I have a parse graph -- how can I use this to figure out the output of the type checker?

The function: `fun f(g) = g(g) + 2;`

The parse graph:
[image]

I would ordinarily just figure this out programmatically, but I don't have the relevant information to do that for this.

Comment: You can't even do this by hand, because you "Don't have the relevant information"?  I don't think you've done your homework.

Comment: No evidence OP has researched the solution.

Comment: The output is an error message.

Answer (score 1):

A sensible approach would be to implement [Algorithm W](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dwikXR0PTXgJ:www.exso.com/courses/cs101a/slides/ml/sml10/node19.html%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk) because Algorithm W will allow you to implement type inference on  a [Hindley-Milner type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) - Hindley-Milner type systems being frequent features of ML family language implementations.